# WCF + Singleton + File transfer + Multithreading

Tags: c#, multithreading, wcf, singleton

I have a file transfer service written using WCF. It recieves a file sent by the client.
The client inturn sends across the file using FileStream + MessageContract. I have made the WCF file transfer service as singleton using the following attributes

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single,
 ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)]
```

I try to use multiple threads in the client itself. 
Each thread creates an instance of channelfactory + proxy.CreateChannel and sends across one distinct file to the service. I do not have any locks on the service side which allows only one file to be transferred at a time, nor on the client side. The code is kind of pass through code with no state persistance.

The problem I am facing is, as such I do not see multiple threads trying to send multiple files. Each time I try to transfer multiple files using multiple threads, the service kind of does not accept multiple files at the same instance. This results in the file getting transferred sequentially instead of in parallel. I feel from the client side the file is sent but at service side its kind of just gets held up.

I tried using ServiceThrottling attributes, but still I do not find any difference.
Is there something wrong which I am doing or is this kind of approach not valid?

One client can only send one file across one channel? Can many threads NOT send many files to the same service ? Can someone please help me.

thanks
Sandeep

Comment: I made it to work, I had a lock object exactly at the entry point of the service. But I am facing one more problem. Only two files are getting transferred at one point. Is there any other configuration pending which I need to add ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hate to admit the silly mistakes I have encountered during this series, but I admit, how silly I was.

1. Reason for single thread execution.
   As I had put a lock right away at the beginning of the service entry, only one thread was allowed while rest waited.
2. Reason for couple of threads getting executed instead of many.
   Since bandwidth is only 2MBPS, and I am trying to transfer 10 files each of 10MB, I am assuming network is getting choked. When I try with 10 files each of 100KB multithreading works like a charm also I am able to control inlet of threads using maxConcurrentCalls.

Cheers, everyone, and thanks YK1

btw. in case I am wrong, please correct my assumption about network bandwidth being culprit.

Answer (score 0):

try setting property `ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit` to value greater than 2 in your client.

Comment: no dude, I removed the whole piece of code, and instead added a simple Debug.Writeline and hosted the service in a console application. To my surprise, I can see that, until one thread completes execution, the next thread is not getting allowed. I tried setting the above property but of little use. At the same time I tried out a sample application which really works like a charm. based on maxConcurrentCalls in serviceThrottling, I can control number of threads into the service. Do not really know what is happening. Is it something to do with MessageContract ?

Comment: Ok - your comment `Only two files are getting transferred at one point.` made me suspect this configuration. I hope you are correctly using the proxy to make concurrent calls - and not waiting for first response to arrive before you make second call.

Comment: Also, by creating proxy in each thread - your client will create multiple connections to the service. Instead create only one proxy and share it among all threads in client - see if this makes any change in behavior

Comment: I cannot share proxy between different threads, because, I have a scenario where multiple files are generated at one instance of time, and I have to send them across to the service. I cannot wait for 1 file to be transferred before another, because, I have 2MBPS line to test (and I am unaware of production bandwidth) and I use https.. so its considerably slow.. 20MB file = 6-7Mins. So I prefer to have multiple proxy one each on different thread. Btw. I am debugging using a console host, will keep you posted ! cheers,